# Why am I getting an error when creating an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

My goal is to create an array of JavaScript objects and would like the output to be in a format like below:

```js
journal = [
  {
    events: ["work", "ice cream", "cauliflower",
      "lasagna", "touched tree", "brushed teeth"
    ],
    squirrel: false
  },
  {
    events: ["weekend", "cycling", "break", "peanuts",
      "soda"
    ],
    squirrel: true
  }

];
```

The goal is to build from the following function with both given parameters (events and squirrel)

```js
let journal = [];

function addEntry(events, squirrel) {
  ...........
  ...........
}
```

I wrote the code below and the output is giving me an error: "false is not a function". How can I fix that error and get the output expected?
Thanks

```js
let journal = [];

function addEntry(events, squirrel) {
  journal.push(
    ({
      events: ["work", "ice cream", "cauliflower", "lasagna", "touched tree", "brushed teeth"]
    }, false)
    ({
      events: ["weekend", "cycling", "break", "peanuts", "soda"]
    }, true)
  )
}
addEntry(console.log(journal));
```

Answer (score 2):

When you push multiple values using `push` you need to separate them by `,`. here you have `(obj,false)()` in this format, since the comma operator returns the last operand, so you actually end up doing `false()`

```js
let journal = [];

function addEntry(events, squirrel) {
  journal.push(
    ({
      events: ["work", "ice cream", "cauliflower", "lasagna", "touched tree", "brushed teeth"]
    }, false),
    ({
      events: ["weekend", "cycling", "break", "peanuts", "soda"]
    }, true)
  )
}
addEntry(journal);
console.log(journal)
```

Here if you intend to push just object you don't need wrapping `()` and also if you need more than one property in your object you can add inside object, like this

```
 {
   key: value,
   key: value
 }
```

```js
let journal = [];

function addEntry(events, squirrel) {
  journal.push({...events,squirrel})
}
addEntry({
    events: ["work", "ice cream", "cauliflower", "lasagna", "touched tree", "brushed teeth"]},true);
addEntry({
    events: ["weekend", "cycling", "break", "peanuts", "soda"]},false)
console.log(journal)
```

Comment: @Stack1 if you need multiple properties inside a object,, you need to add it as key value pair separated by `,`, refresh and see the updated answer

Comment: The way you did is as the first object was the first parameter (events) and the second object was the second parameter (squirrel). I have to have true or false since in each object there should be the first and second parameter.

Comment: I guess what they're looking for  is just `addEntry(events, squirrel) = .push({events, squirrel})`

Comment: @Stack1 i am not getting what you're saying. can you explain with an example ? can you update your question with the desired output ?

Comment: @georg yes may be, it so hard to guess this is what OP meant or not, with the provided example code

Comment: They want the output to match the above as I said in my question. The example code is from me and is not working.

Comment: @Stack1 you can pass the value in function one by one, see the second code snippet in answer

Comment: I did that and it works but the only problem is that it gives me a third object of undefined.

Comment: @Stack1 what do you mean by third object undefined, can you show the code you're trying, please create a fiddle, [`JS fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/) here and share.

Comment: I tried js fiddle but it gave me a blank page @code Maniac

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax in is incorrect

1. You passed result of `console.log` method to `addEntry` method, this is no meaning
2. You used `()` in your addEntry method `({ events: [...] }, false)`, this is a syntax error, you need to push an object (wrapper by `{}`, like this: `({ events: [...], squirrel : false })`

This is example code:

```
let journal = [];

function addEntry(events) {
  events.forEach(event => journal.push(event));
}

let events = [
    {
        events: ["work", "ice cream", "cauliflower",
          "lasagna", "touched tree", "brushed teeth"
        ],
        squirrel: false,
    },
    {
        events: ["weekend", "cycling", "break", "peanuts",
          "soda"
        ],
        squirrel: true
    }
]

addEntry(events);
console.log(journal);
```

Comment: You changed the code by removing the parameter squirrel. It's easy like that. They want to keep both parameters and get the expected output.